Confused by Linux File Times
I am writing some code to manage file times (atime, ctime, and mtime) for a LittleFS file system.  In my desire to make this somewhat Linux/Posix like I ran into questions as to when these times are set in the life-cycle.  Questions like is atime updated when you open a file, read a record, or close that file.  In order to answer these questions I fired up my WSL subsystem and wrote a quick test.  Quite supprised by the results to the point of questioning my hold on reality.  The times didn't change at all during the execution of the program.  Are stats cached?  How can they be refreshed?
Here's the test program:
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* mytime(const time_t *timep)
{
    struct tm *tm = localtime(timep);
    static char text[20];
    sprintf(text, "%d:%02d:%02d", tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
    return text;
}

void test_stat(const char *filename)
{
    printf("Stat of %s ", filename);
    struct stat statbuf = { 0 };
    int rc = stat(filename, &statbuf);
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        printf("stat rc=%d, errno=%d, %s\n", rc, errno, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    printf("st_atime=%s, st_ctime=%s, st_mtime=%s\n",
           mytime(&statbuf.st_atime),
           mytime(&statbuf.st_ctime), mytime(&statbuf.st_mtime));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    static const char *filename = "testfile";
    static int perm = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;

    test_stat(filename);

    int fh = open(filename, 0, perm);
    if (fh < 0)
    {
        printf("open rc=%d, errno=%d, %s\n", fh, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        test_stat(filename);
    }

    printf("Open Create\n");
    fh = open(filename, O_CREAT, perm);
    if (fh < 0)
    {
        printf("open O_CREAT rc=%d, errno=%d, %s\n", fh, errno,
               strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        test_stat(filename);
    }

    printf("Write\n");
    char *buffer = "1234567890";
    write(fh, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    test_stat(filename);

    printf("Close fh=%d\n", fh);
    int rc = close(fh);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        printf("close rc=%d, errno=%d, %s\n", rc, errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    sleep(2);

    test_stat(filename);

    sleep(2);

    printf("Reopen, O_RDWR\n");
    fh = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    if (fh < 0)
    {
        printf("open rc=%d, errno=%d, %s\n", fh, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        test_stat(filename);
    }

    printf("Write more\n");
    write(fh, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    test_stat(filename);

    printf("Close\n");
    rc = close(fh);
    if (fh < 0)
    {
        printf("close rc=%d, errno=%d, %s\n", fh, errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    test_stat(filename);

    sleep(2);

    printf("Reopen, O_WRONLY\n");
    fh = open(filename, O_WRONLY);
    if (fh < 0)
    {
        printf("open rc=%d, errno=%d, %s\n", fh, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        test_stat(filename);
    }

    printf("Write more\n");
    write(fh, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    test_stat(filename);

    printf("Close\n");
    rc = close(fh);
    if (fh < 0)
    {
        printf("close rc=%d, errno=%d, %s\n", fh, errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    test_stat(filename);

    sleep(2);
}

And the results:
waynej@SV3273:~/testTimes$ rm -f testfile; cc -o testTimes testTimes.c && ./testTimes
Stat of testfile stat rc=-1, errno=2, No such file or directory
open rc=-1, errno=2, No such file or directory
Open Create
Stat of testfile st_atime=10:06:48, st_ctime=10:06:48, st_mtime=10:06:48
Write
Stat of testfile st_atime=10:06:48, st_ctime=10:06:48, st_mtime=10:06:48
Close fh=3
Stat of testfile st_atime=10:06:48, st_ctime=10:06:48, st_mtime=10:06:48
Reopen, O_RDWR
Stat of testfile st_atime=10:06:48, st_ctime=10:06:48, st_mtime=10:06:48
Write more
Stat of testfile st_atime=10:06:48, st_ctime=10:06:48, st_mtime=10:06:48
Close
Stat of testfile st_atime=10:06:48, st_ctime=10:06:48, st_mtime=10:06:48
Reopen, O_WRONLY
Stat of testfile st_atime=10:06:48, st_ctime=10:06:48, st_mtime=10:06:48
Write more
Stat of testfile st_atime=10:06:48, st_ctime=10:06:48, st_mtime=10:06:48
Close
Stat of testfile st_atime=10:06:48, st_ctime=10:06:48, st_mtime=10:06:48


printf("st_atime=%s, st_ctime=%s, st_mtime=%s\n",
           mytime(&statbuf.st_atime),
           mytime(&statbuf.st_ctime), 
           mytime(&statbuf.st_mtime));

Now explain to your nearest rubber duck how you expect printf to print three different strings when mytime returns
static char text[20];

every single time.
That's your problem right here. Don't do static variables. They will bite you.

Aaah, quite right.  I was trying to be too quick and dirty.  Thanks.
